# Ngrx and Angular Resolver

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

im having a problem with ngrx and my resolver in angular. I know the problem but i don't find a solution for it. I am selecting an account from my ngrx store and end the obs with the take(1), but because of the take(1) it always takes the first value so when i emit a new value the resolver doesnt get it. Can someone help me?

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Account> {
    const id = this.getParameter(route, 'accountId');

    if (id) {
      this._store.dispatch(AccountsPageActions.loadAccountWithDetails({ accountId: id }));
      return this._store.select(getAccountDetailById(id)).pipe(
        switchMap(account => this._store.select(getAccountError).pipe(
          map(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.message.includes(id)) {
              this._utilService.showErrorToast('Zugang nicht gefunden');
              this._router.navigateByUrl('/');
            }
            console.log(account);
            return account
          })
        )),
        skipWhile(account => account?.id !== id),
        take(1)
      );
    }

    return null;
  }
```

**Edit:** The problem is i trigger the resolver in the same route.
Example: I am opening an accordion item --> redirect to /account/{accountId1} and if i then open another accordion item i need to redirect to /account/{accountId2} but the resolver doesnt resolve because it doesnt get a new value with the new account.

Comment: and why do you need the `take(1)` ?

Comment: Have you tried using `takeLast(1)` instead ?

Comment: @TobiasS. Because the resolver needs an completed Observable and the ngrx selector observable never gets completeted, thats why i need take(1)

Comment: @Andres2142 Doesnt't work, but thanks

Comment: If you add a `console.log('RESOLVING')` before `const id = this.getParameter...`, does it fire when you navigate to another ID?

Comment: @dallows Yes it fire the function but not the observable..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The resolver was not my problem..

Had a problem with the angular material mat-tab-accordion